# Domain does not work without dot in the en

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, route53

Why my domain works only when I type this: example.com. with a "dot" and without "www" and in any other condition I get 400 error:

```
http://example.com./ - it works
http://www.example.com/ - it doesn't work
http://www.example.com./ - it doesn't work
```

Error I get:
`GET http://www.example.com./ 400 (Bad Request)`

I use: django, aws, route53, ec2, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

[I followed this tutorial 1:1](https://medium.com/@yashpatel007/how-to-connect-your-amazon-ec2-instance-with-a-domain-name-80ad8959078):

I set up:

1. elastic IP for my instance and connnect to my instance.
2. In hosted zone I did like in tutorial:

   > Record name:
   > example.com
   > Record type:
   > A
   > Value:
   > my IP
   > Alias:
   > No
   > TTL (seconds):
   > 300
   > Routing policy:
   > Simple

and

```
> Record name:
> www.example.com
> Record type:
> A
> Value:
> example.com.
> Alias:
> No
> TTL (seconds):
> 900
> Routing policy:
> Simple
```

3)Nginx conf:

````
```
server {     
listen 80 default_server;     
server_name example.com www.example.com myIP;}
```
````

then restart:

````
```
sudo systemctl restart nginx 
sudo service gunicorn restart 
sudo service nginx restart
```
````

4. Settings.py:

   `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ 'example.com','myIP', ]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a client-side issue, as the dot only changes client DNS behavior – can you check whether `ipconfig /all` or `cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows a "domain search suffix" on your client system?